# How does one embed an image in a component?

Tags: angular, webpack

How do you embed images in Angular 2 HTML components?

When I use an absolute path, the image simply does not load.

**Absolute Path:**

```
<img src="/images/1.jpeg" alt="logo">
```

When I try a relative path, I get an error referring to the image loader in my webpack.config file.

**Relative Path:**

```
<img src="../../../../../images/1.jpeg" alt="logo">
```

**Relative Path Error:**

```
Can't resolve 'file-loader?name=images/[name].[hash].[ext]'
```

I am very confused and would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the path to the image and the path to your main.ts file, or your app.ts file?

Comment: Sorry.. the path to my app.ts file as in my app.component.ts file?

And the image paths are in the question, right?

Comment: Did you scaffold your project using the Angular CLI?

Comment: No, I used some generator..